# Center content over a image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center a little self made caption over a image, but its not quite working right. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but here is a fiddle that shows what i am working with: https://jsfiddle.net/efvL28o0/.

html

```
<div class= "container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="rel-tile" >
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" width="100%">
            <span class="btn-center text-center caption-custom">About Me</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="rel-tile">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt="" width="100%">
            <span class="btn-center text-center">Lineage</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="rel-tile">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt="" width="100%">
            <span class="btn-center text-center">Contact Me</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <a href="" class="rel-tile">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000x500" alt="" width="100%">
            <span class="btn-center text-center">Gallery</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
        .rel-tile {
        position: relative;
    }

    .btn-center {
        position: absolute;
        top: 45%;
        opacity: 0.6;
        left:45%;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Ideally it would float exactly in the middle regardless of the size i set for the btn-center.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bsalex/byqa4qng/3/

Change `.btn-center` styles to:

```
.btn-center {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            opacity: 0.6;
            left:50%;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }
```

The main part here is `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`.
It is one of the common centering techniques.